# Generating form_Closing for c sharp in visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, formclosing

We can generate form_Load() for c sharp in visual studio by just double clicking the form in design view. Is there a same kind of procedure to generate form_Closing() too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the properties for the object you have selected (usually bottom right side), you'll see a lightning bolt.  Click it, and you'll see all the events that are available for that object.  Double click by one of the events and voila!

Answer (score 2):

Go the the form properties <kbd>F4</kbd>, scroll to the close event, double click it or type in the name of the event handler that you want. The event handler will be generated for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same in the constructor of the form

```
this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form2_FormClosing);
//after += two tabs and you have your event
```